# Should I relocate the HVAC unit in my attic?

Tags: hvac, furnace, attic, placement

I have had a couple of estimates to replace our HVAC system and one contractor says he would relocate the system to a more central location in the attic. One says there is no need to relocate. There is an additional cost to this relocation, of course. The unit is set on one side of the house in the attic.

Any thoughts on what I should ask and if this is necessary?

Answer (score 10):

Necessary? 
No.

More efficient?  Yes.

When the HVAC is centrally located the warmer/cooler air has less overall distance to travel to cover the entire house, as it's radiating out from the center.

If you have noticed that one side of your house is less comfortable than the other, it may be worth the relocation.  If the house is generally comfortable year round already when the system is operating, I would not bother with moving the new one.